# Highly-upvoted comments on Meta have less emphasis than lowly-voted comments

Tags: bug, comments, design, meta

On Meta Stack Exchange, highly-voted comments have a less-intense color than lowly-voted comments:

[image: comment votes]

The low-voted comments are red, the medium are blue, and the highest-voted are black. This seems backwards from how it ought to be.

[This is the question I observed it on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/139837). There's a wide range of comment votes, making it a good example of the issue.

Comment: The real question is why those numbers need the sorbet coloration at all?

Comment: @CareBear thanks - I tried to find a previous bug report, but that post was miscategorized as a feature request.